# Uninstall uv python package installer

Tags: python-3.x, python-packaging

I recently installed [uv](https://github.com/astral-sh/uv) on linux using the command line provided in the documentation:

```bash
curl -LsSf https://astral.sh/uv/install.sh | sh
```

It created an executable in `/home/currentuser/.cargo/bin/uv`. Now, just out of curiosity, I would like to know how to remove it properly. Is it as simple as deleting the file ? Or is there any script or command line which are cleaner ?

Please note that I also tried with `pip install/uninstall uv` and it worked perfectly, but the installation path was different.
Thanks.

Comment: Actually I just discovered that there is an [issue](https://github.com/astral-sh/uv/issues/1696) about this so maybe I was too much in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

I the installation script they say

```
This script .. unpacks the binaries and installs them to \$CARGO_HOME/bin 
(\$HOME/.cargo/bin)

It will then add that dir to PATH by adding the appropriate line to your 
shell profiles.
```

So you can just remove the file and that's all.
Also you can remove the `. "$HOME/.cargo/env"` they added to you shell rc file but this is not necessary.

BTW they do have task to add uninstall docs
https://github.com/astral-sh/uv/issues/1696
so later we will see official instruction..